# If X ∼ N(µ, σ2 ) find the pdf of Y = e ^ X.

Tags: probability

Help? I am stuck on this homework question and finding very difficult to answer

Comment: Check [lognormal distribution] ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**An approach (outline):** you can for instance go through the cumulative distribution function, then differentiate it to get the pdf ($f_Y(x) = F^\prime_Y(x)$).
For $x \in\mathbb{R}$,
$$F_Y(x) = \mathbb{P}\{ Y \leq x \} = \mathbb{P}\{ e^X \leq x \}.$$

If $ x \leq 0$, this probability is $0$ as $e^X \geq 0$ a.s. For $x > 0$, you get

$$F_Y(x) = \mathbb{P}\{ e^X \leq x \}= \mathbb{P}\{ X \leq \ln x \} = F_X(\ln x)$$
which you know explicitly (as $X$ is Gaussian with known parameters).